# Remove numbers and short words from search keywords

Tags: php

I have an insert query which adds various words into a search table, for use in a keyword search for my site, based on existing content from other tables.

My issue is that, although I have a common words text file which excludes words like 'and' and 'the', I also wish to eliminate numbers and words less than 3 characters in length.

Can anyone help?

```
$stripChars = array('.', ',', '!', '?', '(', ')', '%', '&', '"', '*', ':', ';', '@', ' - ', '/', '\\');
$string = str_replace($stripChars, ' ', $string);

$string = str_replace('  ', ' ', $string);
$words = explode(' ', $string);

return array_diff($words, $this->commonwords);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you are trying to achieve with a structured Regex call, in PHP using the function [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php). However, looking at the code on your question there is a lot that can be improved simply by employing the correct Regex with the Preg_replace function:

> ```
> $stripChars = array('.', ',', '!', '?', '(', ')', '%', '&', '"', '*', ':', ';', '@', ' - ', '/', '\\');
> $string = str_replace($stripChars, ' ', $string);
> ```

Lets face it, this isn't very articulate to look at. 
Assuming you're simply trying to remove non-alphanumeric characters this can be simplified down to:

```
$string = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9_\s-]/i","",$string);
```

Which is telling PHP to replace all characters which are *not* (indicated by the `^` carat): a-z (the `/i` indicates case insensitive) and not 0-9 and not underscore `_` and not a whitespace character `\s` or a dash `-`. These are then replaced with nothing (second string section) and so are effectively removed.

You can obviously adjust what appears in the square brackets to suit your needs (see later on as this will occur...).

Adding in to this your next section:

> ```
> $string = str_replace('  ', ' ', $string);
> ```

Which appears to be you want to replace multiple spaces with a single space character, again, `preg_replace` can do this nice and concisely for you:

```
 $string = preg_replace("/\s+/", " ",$string);
```

Where `\s` is the whitespace character, and the `+` sign indicates to return "greedy and as many as possible".

And your original request, which was for removing numbers and words of 2 or less characters, preg_replace can use the code from part 1 of this answer simply to include numbers as well, by omitting numbers from the `[^a-z0-9_\s-]` block, thus: `[^a-z_\s-]` numbers will now be removed.

To remove short words you can use:

```
$string = preg_replace("/\b[a-z]{1,2}\b/i","",$string);
```

This will outline words with a word boundary `\b` and then defined that any collection of those characters in the square brackets `[a-z]` of length between minimum 1 and maximum 2 `{1,2}` should be marked, and the `\i` makes it case insensitive again, thus removing these words.

Wrapping it all together you then have:

```
///remove anything that is not letters or underscore or whitespace
$string = preg_replace("/[^a-z_\s-]/i","",$string); 
/// remove short words
$string = preg_replace("/\b[a-z]{1,2}\b/i","",$string);
/// finally remove excess whitespaces 
$string = preg_replace("/\s+/", " ",$string);
```

The removal of whitespaces is put last as removing short words would leave the space each side of the word so thus causes longer whitespace blocks.

There may well be a way of combining the Regex into a single (or at least, fewer) query/ies, but I'm not very good at combining regex calls I'm afraid. But the code above is much smarter, neater and more powerful than your current code. As well as answering your question.

**EDIT:**

To remove just numbers specifically you can use the following `preg_replace` code:

```
$string = preg_replace("/\d+/","",$string);
```

Comment: Thank you for such an informed answer.  Really appreaciate it. Your solution works great.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this to remove words less than 3 characters:

```
$replaced = preg_replace('~\b[a-z]{1,2}\b\~', '', $text);
```

also use this to remove numbers:

```
$replaced = preg_replace('/[0-9]+/', '', $text);
```

Comment: Removing numbers can also be done with the `\d` wildcard specifier

Comment: I would also suggest you make your word removal case insensitive, as your current example `At` would not be removed.

Comment: Why search words should be case sensitive?